# Python: How can I access CSV like a matrix?

Tags: python, csv, python-module

I don't want to manually do the part of parsing the CSV and I will need to access the cell in this fashion:

```
Cells (row, column) = X
```

or

```
X = Cells (row, column)
```

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a CSV file and would like to treat it as an array:

You could use `genfromtxt` from the [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) module, this will make a numpy array with as many rows and columns as are in your file (`X` in code below).Assuming the data is all numerical you can use `savetxt` to store values in the csv file:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.genfromtxt("yourcsvfile.dat",delimiter=",")
X[0,0] = 42   # do something with the array
np.savetxt('yourcsvfile.dat',X,delimiter=",")
```

**EDIT:**

If there are strings in the file you can do this:

```
# read in
X = np.genfromtxt("yourcsvfile.dat",delimiter=",",dtype=None)
# write out
with open('yourcsvfile.dat','w') as f:
for el in X[()]:
    f.write(str(el)+' ')
```

Some other techniques in answers here:

[numpy save an array of different types to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881817/numpy-save-an-array-of-different-types-to-a-text-file)

[How do I import data with different types from file into a Python Numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481523/how-do-i-import-data-with-different-types-from-file-into-a-python-numpy-array)

Comment: I have a few strings and a few time/date too in my CSV, will they be pruned? Thanks

Comment: Dealing with data types, missing data, indexing by column number instead of name... this is just part of the reason why this should *not* be the accepted answer. Pandas (as suggested by @kleino) is a far better option.

Answer (score 3):

numpy is nice but is a bit overkill for such a simple requirement.

Try:

```
import csv
sheet = list(csv.reader(open(source_csv_location)))
print sheet[0][0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the amount of sophistication you need, [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) might be nice.

```
import pandas as pd
location = r'C:\path\to\your\file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(location, names=['Names','Births'])

df['Births'].plot()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Pandas wraps numpy with lots of convenience so there really is no need to use the low-level numpy approach.