# numpy.savetxt IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: csv, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array with the following attributes:

```
print(matrix.shape)
(30000, 1000)

print(matrix)
(0, 208)      0.107297742751
(0, 666)      0.107413554001
(0, 833)      0.090485141939
(0, 616)      0.090485141939
..
..
```

When I try to write the array to a file I get:

```
numpy.savetxt('matrix.csv', matrix, delimiter=',')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-412b5d26d905> in <module>()
----> 1 numpy.savetxt('matrix.csv', matrix, delimiter=',')

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments)
   1042                 ncol = len(X.dtype.descr)
   1043         else:
-> 1044             ncol = X.shape[1]
   1045 
   1046         iscomplex_X = np.iscomplexobj(X)

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881817/numpy-save-an-array-of-different-types-to-a-text-file

Comment: If the answer's there I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the output of `print(matrix)`, it is apparent that `matrix` is an instance of [`scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html). Such a matrix is not a numpy array; numpy knows nothing about scipy sparse matrices.  In particular, `numpy.savetxt` doesn't handle scipy's sparse matrices.

For a suggestion on how to save a sparse matrix to a text file, see my answer to a different question here: [How to format in numpy savetxt such that zeros are saved only as "0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691755/how-to-format-in-numpy-savetxt-such-that-zeros-are-saved-only-as-0/24699373#24699373)