# Problems saving a big matrix as a .csv file ""

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I would like to save a big matrix as a `.csv` file. However, from [numpy's documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) I tried the following:

```
training_matrix = dict_vect.fit_transform(training_data_2_dict)
csv_matrix = np.savetxt("foo.csv", training_matrix, delimiter=",")
```

This is the shape of the matrix: `(878049, 413439)` and this is the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/kaggle/modeling_the_problem.py", line 55, in <module>
    training_matrix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1044, in savetxt
    ncol = X.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Any idea of how to save the matrix in a csv file?.

Comment: What exactly is `training_matrix`?  Plain `numpy` array?  Or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @hpaulj, it's a sparse scikit-learn matrix.... I guess that is a numpy array.... Anyhow, I tried to convert it to a numpy array and still can solve this issue.

Comment: A sparse matrix is not a numpy array.  Use `todense`, `toarray` or `.D`,`.A` to convert it to a regular dense matrix or array.   Just be ware that the saved text will have a lot of 0s - and 413439 'columns' (very long lines).

Comment: Thanks But I also tried` toarray()` but it chrashes my computer...

Comment: Probably the dense version is too big for your memory.  What do you expect, or want to see, in the `csv` file?  Slews of zeros?  Have you tried converting a few rows of the matrix?  Tried writing those?

Comment: `np.savetxt` just writes a header to the file, and then writes the array one 'row' at a time.  Look at its code.  Notice how it replicates the `fmt`, and then does a `fmt%tuple(row)`.  So if know how to convert your array to strings, row by row, you can write the file yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the matrix happens to be a scipy matrix, then numpy will encounter this in effort to save. If so, the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327568/numpy-savetxt-indexerror-tuple-index-out-of-range) should explain.

Comment: Thanks for the help!. Do you think it is possible to convert this scipy matrix to a numpy array and then save it to a file?.